# Good way of implementing flux terms for the elastic wave equation using the SIPG method in MATLAB?

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, finite-element-method

I am currently trying to solve the elastic wave equation using dG with symmetric interior penalties, and i seem to run into some problems regarding the discretization of the numerical flux. The flux-term i want to implement looks like

$$J=\int_\gamma \bigg([\phi]\{\sigma(u)\cdot n\}+\{\sigma(\phi)\cdot n\}[u]-\frac{\beta}{h}[\phi][u]\bigg) d\gamma$$
where $\phi$ would be a test field that is suitably nice, $u=[u_1,u_2]^T$ is the displacement field and $\sigma(u)$ the stress tensor. I have heard some people wanting to use the Voight notation, which seems reasonable but i cannot quite get it to work. I have tried writing the overall integramd above on the form

$$C^T\mathcal{T}\xi+\mathcal{T}^TC\xi-\frac{\beta}{h}C^TC\xi,$$
where $\xi=[\xi^+,\xi^-]^T$ are the degrees of freedom on the positive and negative element adjacent to $\gamma$ respectively, and

$$C=\begin{bmatrix}C^+ & 0 \\ 0 & -C^-\end{bmatrix}$$
is a matrix only containing the basis functions on each element, and $\mathcal{T}$ gives the Voight form of the stress tensor, i.e we have that

$$\mathcal{T}=\begin{bmatrix}NDB^+ & 0 \\ 0 & NDB^-\end{bmatrix}$$
with $D$ containing the Lamé parameters, $N=\begin{bmatrix}n_1 & 0 &n_2 \\ 0 & n_2 & n_1\end{bmatrix}$ a matrix containing the outward unit normal from the positive element and $B$ a matrix containing the derivatives of the basis functions so that

$$B^\pm\xi^\pm=\varepsilon_v^\pm=(\varepsilon^\pm_1,\varepsilon^\pm_2,2\varepsilon^\pm_{12})^T.$$

With this formulation i have also run into the problem of how the components of the total matrix in the integrand should be sent out to the global flux matrix. What would be a clear way of doing this? I feel like there arises some difficulties if you e.g. consider the degrees of freedom be ordered at each element as $\xi^+=[\xi^+_x,\xi^+_y]^T$ which i want to have in order to be compatible with another code i want to use this with later on.

So to summarize the questions:

1. Is the Voight method best? Or do you use any other way of evaluating the integrand?
2. How do you map it to the global flux matrix in an efficient manner

Thanks in advance!